# No user input after upgrading to ubuntu 14.10 with linux kernel 3.16

Tags: upgrade, kernel, keyboard, input-devices

After upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10, I am no longer able to use my keyboard and mouse to do anything. I can't even get to a tty terminal. All I can do is stare at the login screen, or do a hard reset.

I suspect the Linux kernel 3.16 because my keyboard and mouse work again after booting into an older kernel version from Grub's 'Advanced Ubuntu Options' page.

My computer is a custom built PC with an AMD chip-set and USB 2.0 and 3.0. (Built around the first of October 2014)

Edit:
My keyboard is a USB HP keyboard from another computer, my mouse is a USB wireless Logitech mouse with unifying receiver.

Edit2:
Clarified information about not being able to use keyboard or mouse to do anything.

Comment: What type of keyboard and mouse do you use? Wireless? USB? PS/2? I don't imagine you use a serial mouse or DIN keyboard...

Comment: I've updated my post to answer your question.

Comment: Do I get you right: You press ctrl-alt-f1 you don't get a tty and that only happens with 3.16 and not with earlier kernels? You also mention the mouse, so my bet is that it's a USB issue...

Comment: Correct. I also get this problem with the Grub 'recovery mode' for kernel 3.16. I have keyboard control in Grub, but not in the recovery environment.

Comment: Do keyboard and mouse work in GNOME? Can you please boot normally, log in and then open a terminal window and paste the output of `sudo dmesg |grep input` and `sudo lsmod|grep usb`?

Comment: Is there some way to setup a script that runs on startup and displays error or boot information from a log file?

Comment: No, I am unable to login because the keyboard doesn't work. I'll clarify that in my post.

Comment: Does it work if you pull out the keyboard and plug it in again when seeing the login screen?

Comment: Nope. Initially, there is the num-lock light on my keyboard. When I unplug and plug it back in, the num-lock light doesn't turn on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18291/discussion-between-jan-and-rj-adam).

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue - for some reason, during the upgrade, my kernel was skipped so I manually upgraded/installed linux-image-3.16.0-24-generic.  It turns out most of the drivers you need live in linux-image-extra-3.16.0-24-generic and you'll need the headers too.  I'm guessing you're missing them as I was.

So, from your working kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-3.16.0-24-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-24-generic
```

Afterwards you should be able to boot into 3.16 and your peripherals will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! For me though, it was the linux-image-extra package which installed the usbhid driver. As I understand, the headers package should only be needed for compiling modules (and possibly other software that relies on kernel ABIs).

Comment: Same fix worked for my Ubuntu 12.04.2 upgrade to 14.04.3 except I had to change the kernel version to 3.19.0-30.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of had the same issue after upgrading. But I could get to tty and by accident found out that GNOME Do was the application to blame for that the keyboard (and mouse) stopped working.

Comment: Same for me , Gnome-Do was the culprit!!