# Updating to 3.19.0-65 broke my Nvidia drivers, reverting back to 3.19.0-64 broke my system

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

System: Ubuntu 14.04, Intel i7, 16GB RAM, GTX 980 video card (usually I run the 352 driver from Nvidia)

So, admittedly I am not very good at Linux. I updated to 3.19.0-65, which (as noted elsewhere) now requires Secure Boot. Nvidia drivers don't work with that, so I wasn't able to log in to the GUI on reboot. I was able to get the system to boot from the GRUB menu to the older 3.19.0-64 kernel in recovery mode, so I tried to purge the 3.19.0-65 kernel in hopes that 3.19.0-64 would become the new default. When I rebooted it was still expecting 3.19.0-65 and the boot failed.

So... cut to several hours later, and I've managed to use boot-repair-disk to fix GRUB and I can boot to the login screen again. I've purged all of the kernels, and installed only two: 3.19.0-64-generic and 3.19.0-64-lowlatency. I've also turned off Secure Boot in both GRUB (deselecting that option in boot-repair-disk) and in my BIOS.

I still can't get into the GUI - it shows the login screen at low resolution but when I put my password in it just kicks me right back to the same screen. Using ubuntu-drivers I can see my video card is "UNCLAIMED" and that doesn't change when I install the driver from a terminal and/or reboot. And that's only in the "lowlatency" kernel - in the "generic" kernel, it takes me to the screen where I enter the passphrase to decrypt my harddrive, and the keyboard doesn't work (no characters appear no matter what I type).

I'm really at a loss here, please let me know what additional information I can provide.

Comment: Disable Secure boot in BIOS.

Comment: I have, it won't boot at all without that.

Answer (score 0):

Found this..

"... my kernel was skipped so I manually upgraded/installed linux-image-3.16.0-24-generic. It turns out most of the drivers you need live in linux-image-extra-3.16.0-24-generic and you'll need the headers too."

Use your working kernel & run the command below *(I believe you'll need to change the kernel version #'s to yours):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-3.16.0-24-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-24-generic
```

source: [askubuntu - "No user input after upgrading to ubuntu 14.10 with linux kernel 3.16"](https://askubuntu.com/a/545414/562148)

I think you ought to temporarily install nouveau/xserver until you find a way to successfully achieve what you initially had planned, **or**...

(**14.04+**) ..If you want to try the newest method for installing Nvidia drivers using '**graphics-drivers**' **PPA**, then see below. It *may* be a bit risky.

---

**Installing the recommended Nvidia driver from PPA**

1. Add the 'graphics-drivers' PPA with these commands:

   - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   - sudo apt-get update
2. Autoinstall the recommended driver with:

   - sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
3. Now reboot with:

   - sudo reboot

If the recommended driver does not work for you, try installing a different Nvidia driver.

(See below)

---

**Installing other Nvidia drivers from PPA**

1. Add the 'graphics-drivers' PPA with:

   - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   - sudo apt-get update
2. Purge existing Nvidia packages you have installed (if any):

   - sudo apt-get purge Nvidia*
3. Check available drivers for your system with this command:

   - ubuntu-drivers devices
4. Install the recommended driver:

   - sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
5. Lastly, reboot with:

   - sudo reboot

source: [askubuntu - "Ubuntu 14.04 install nVidia driver"](https://askubuntu.com/a/700613/562148)

Comment: I don't have a "working kernel" but I am able to use a live USB to mount the filesystem and chroot into it as in these instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels

Comment: I used apt-get to install linux-image-3.19.0-64-generic,  that's the kernel that won't let me type anything. I tried installing linux-image-3.19.0-24-generic but it says it can't find that package.

Comment: And that is the method I used to install the drivers. But the card still shows up as UNCLAIMED